# What is int operator()

Tags: c++, function, int, operator-keyword

What is the meaning of the line **int operator ()(int n)** ?

It looks like a function but what is it?

```
class collatzer
{
private:
    int counter = 0;

public:
    int operator ()(int n)
    {
        if(n==1)
            return counter;

        else if(n%2==0) //if n is even
        {
            counter += 1;
            return (*this)(n / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            counter += 1;
            return (*this)(3 * n + 1);
        }
    }

    int getCounter()
    {
        return counter;
    }
};
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Comment: Perhaps you need [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282)?